# Keyboard shortcut to blank screen Xfce/Xubuntu

Tags: xfce

does anyone know the command to blank the screen in Xfce/Xubuntu?

Comment: @guiverc I read the answer on your linked duplicate target and my answer to this question was accepted, so I can confirm that these two questions are not duplicates of each other and so can you by comparing both answers. The close vote was a false positive. Please retract it.

Comment: To be fair, guiverc read the preceding  comment, retracted his close vote and removed the comment that identified this question as a duplicate. Thanks @guiverc for that. I will leave the preceding comment in place temporarily to inform other reviewers of this question about what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blank the screen immediately:

```
xset dpms force off
```

You can click the blank screen to restore it or restore it using the following command:

```
xset dpms force on
```

Blank and lock the screen:

```
xflock4 -b
```

There is no default keyboard shortcut to blank the screen. Assign your choice of keyboard shortcut as follows:

1. Go to *Settings Manager* -> *Keyboard*-> *Application Shortcuts*.
2. Click *Add*.
3. In the *Command* field, enter `xset dpms force off`.
4. Hold down the desired shortcut key combination.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help, karel. I've mapped super + B to "xset dpms force off". Upon executing the command, the screen fully blanks (no power to the screen) and then goes dark (black, but backlight still on) and then goes fully blank again. That seems to work well, except the command also locks the screen. I live in a domicile with 2 computer illiterate roommates so the security risk is not zero, but "very low" :-) . Do you know of a similar command that doesn't lock the screen?

Comment: On my computer which has a single boot of Ubuntu 22.04 installed `xset dpms force off` blanks the screen without locking it and `xflock4 -b` blanks and locks the screen. I added this to my answer. If this answered your question, you can mark this answer as accepted by clicking the gray check mark beside the answer to change its color to green.

Comment: I'm running Xubuntu 22.04 single boot. Perhaps we just have different machines. I'm using a Dell Latitude laptop. Currently, I hold down the fn button and the down arrow which gradually dims the screen until completely blank